# Rails5 API that interacts with external API best practices

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, service, adapter, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm designing a Rails 5 API for a Stock Portfolio simulation game I'm building. Part of the build is interacting with an external API to pull most recent stock prices, which I can then in turn run analytics.

My question: what are best practices for interacting with the external API? I'll likely be using Net/HTTP to actually make the calls, but where should I put that code? I could put this directly in one of the models, however I'd like to separate the interactions to the external API, in the event that the API may not be supported in the future.

Other things I'm considering: 
- Create a class or module and put it in the lib folder
- Create a service
- Create a adapter

Would love to hear everyone's thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep the code in lib folder (or you can create lib/external folder if you have many external apis). Every service should be in separate class or module. But often the service consists of a module and multiple classes to access to separate resources.

```
# files
boats_api/
  boat.rb
  boat_list.rb
boats_api.rb

# usage
BoatsApi::Boat.find('boat')
BoatsApi::BoatList.all(page: 2)
```